# How i can ignore 0 values from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, panel, point

I'm trying to ignore some 0 on a plot but I'm not finding a way to do it.
i tried to use filter and which but I obtain the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rDLC.png) `"Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1980): y"`

above there is the code I'm using.

```
ggplot(data=PRICE_MSCI_MODEL_10_PAESI,aes(x=t,y=fitted_values99,group = 1))+
+   geom_line(color = "steelblue")+
+   geom_point(aes(x=t,y=which(D99!=0),colour="red"))+
+   facet_wrap(~id)
```

> Errore: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
> (1980): y

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter your data beforehand:

```
new_df <- PRICE_MSCI_MODEL_10_PAESI[PRICE_MSCI_MODEL_10_PAESI$D99 != 0, ]
ggplot(data = new_df, aes(...
```

Alternatively, you can enter this directly into `ggplot()`:

```
ggplot(data = PRICE_MSCI_MODEL_10_PAESI[PRICE_MSCI_MODEL_10_PAESI$D99 != 0, ], aes(...
```

Comment: thanks, i obtain the same error :(

Comment: okay, it's hard to tell without a data snippet... but have you tried to additionally remove the `aes(...)` part from the `geom_point()` line? It should be enough to specify your aesthetics once in your case

Comment: no way, the thing is that removing the 0 the dimension of x and y differ and r does not create the plot, could sound an idea to put the 0 point transparent, do u have an idea on how to do that?

Comment: and where u able to see the figure that i'v attached?

Comment: yes, I see the screenshot. but without a reproducible example, it is hard for me to fully understand the issue I'm afraid

Comment: ok thanks anyway :)